# Need SQL Query to find Parent records without child records

Tags: sql

I am not at all conversant in SQL so was hoping someone could help me with a query that will find all the records in a parent table for which there are no records in a child table.

The following works for me to find parent records for specific child field values...

```
`SELECT    ParentTable.ParentID
 FROM      ParentTable INNER JOIN
             ParentTable ON ParentTable.ParentID = ChildTable.ChildID
 WHERE     (ChildTable.ChildField_ = '2131')
 Group By
   ParentTable.ParentID
 Having
   count(distinct ChildTable.ChildField) > 0`
```

Can I change the where clause some how to find parent's with a count of zero child records.

Thanks.

Comment: Haven't you just changed `>` with `=` in `HAVING` clause?

Comment: user278859 if you are appling simple inner join it will not give desired parent id till where clouse (before group by will execute)... so either you have to use not exist or left or right join as suggested by phil...

@zerkms :- then you will not get any records after appling ` = ` sign over there

Comment: I dont understand the fact that the above question got so many upvotes

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause for this

```
SELECT ParentTable.ParentID
FROM ParentTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ChildTable
    WHERE ChildTable.ParentID = ParentTable.ParentID
)
```

There's also the old *left join and check for null* approach

```
SELECT ParentTable.ParentID
FROM ParentTable
LEFT JOIN ChildTable
  ON ParentTable.ParentID = ChildTable.ParentID
WHERE ChildTable.ChildID IS NULL
```

Try both and see which one works better for you.

Comment: why you have used left join here?

Comment: The second example is incorrect.

Comment: @kicaj care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

Outer join parent to child, and then having count(*) = 0.

```
select
  p.parent_id,
  count(*)
from
  parent p left outer join child c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
group by
  p.parent_id
having
  count(*) = 0
```

Comment: in question need record for parent having no child... so have you not change query to  `p.parent_id = c.parent_id*  `.. in oracle same kind of work has to done by  `(+) ` and should add in child table (in this case)

Comment: Yes, outer join from parent to child will still return parents even when there are no children - count(*) will be 0.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a left join on the child table and simply say where the child parentID is null.

```
SELECT ParentTable.ParentID FROM ParentTable P
    Left Join ChildTable C on C.ParentID = P.ParentID
    WHERE C.Id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

With another example as

### Enumerate table

```
    id: SERIAL
    name: TEXT
    enumerate_id: INT
```

### All parents who have children (all branches of a tree, even roots, but no leaf!)

```
SELECT id, name, enumerate_id
FROM enumerate p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM enumerate c
    WHERE c.enumerate_id = p.id
);
```

### All children who don't have children (all leafs of a tree)

```
SELECT id, name, enumerate_id
FROM enumerate p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM enumerate c
    WHERE c.enumerate_id = p.id
);
```

> Note that the only one who changes is the `NOT` EXISTS

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM ParentTable WHERE ParentID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentID FROM ChildTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply dont understand whats the `having` clause doing in your query as I see already you are saying  `where
ChildTable.ChildField_ = '2131'` that already means you have record set for childfield 2131 
Try the below query it would mean that if the parent doesnt have child in the Childtable with field 2131then o/p the same.

```
     SELECT    ParentTable.ParentID
         FROM      ParentTable 
         Where ParentTable.ParentID NOT IN (Select ChildID 
        From ChildTable where
         ChildTable.ChildField_ = '2131')
```