# Real left outer join

Tags: mysql, join

How do I perform a real left outer join in mysql? it seems it's left outer join includes the inner join. I need to find records in table `a` that are not in table `b`.
The best I could come up with is

```
select * from `a` where `a`.`index` not in (select `index` from `b`)
```

Is there any more optimized way? without subquery maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need SQL Query to find Parent records without child records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839500/need-sql-query-to-find-parent-records-without-child-records)

Comment: What you're describing is not a left outer join. A left join contains all records in table `a`, regardless of whether there are matching records in table `b`.

Comment: I'd recommend using `not exists` over `not in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it w/ a left join:

```
select * 
from `a`
left outer join `b`
on `a`.`index` = `b`.`index`
where `b`.`index` is null
```

Comment: I agree this works, but I've been told by more than one DBA to avoid this type of query - something to do with how the database engine can't optimize this properly, so the performance suffers. I don't know if that's true or not, but it's probably at least worth doing some performance testing against the other methods.

Comment: @Joe, it really depends on the database... MySql isn't great with subqueries, either, so I don't think it'll matter too much, here.

Comment: @jswolf19: That makes sense. My advice came from SQL Server and Oracle DBAs, but it wouldn't surprise me to find MySQL's optimizer behaving differently.