# MySQL get data from 2 tables based on a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables in MySQL database which are :

1) supplier  **(Used to save all supplier)**
2) vehicle   **(Used to get all vehicles )**
3) assigned  **(Used to book the vehicle for certain booking)**
4) booking   **(Used to save all new booking)**

**vehicle table structure:**

```
vid     vehicleName    sid
==========================
13      xx             28
14      xx             28
15      xx             28
16      xx             29
17      xx             29
18      xx             30
```

**assigned table structure:**

```
asgid    bid   sid   vid   did    assigned_start   assigned_end
===============================================================
42       15    28    15    16     1527804060       1527811320
43       15    28    14    15     1527804060       1527811320
```

In **reservation** page I am getting a new booking date to **assign a vehicle** which will start on **1527804060** and end **1527811320**. (It's basically 06/01/2018 02:01 to 04:02)

Now on this reservation page, I can show all supplier name and their vehicle name from supplier and vehicle table (see my bellow query). That's good.

But I want to show those vehicles which **is not** already booked between this `assigned_start` and `assinged_end` date.

**For example:** You can see that `vid` 15 and 14 is already **assigned** to the **same** old and new booking date. Now, a query should show me only 13, 16, 17, 18 no vehicle. **Not**, 15 and 14 because they are booked between the date

**Current query to show all vehicle with corresponding supplier name:**

```
foreach ($sid as $key => $value) {
    $vehicle->rowQuery("SELECT s.supplierName, v.vid, vehicleName, v.noOfSeat, v.seatBooked, v.type 
                        FROM vehicle AS v 
                        LEFT JOIN supplier AS s ON v.sid = s.sid 
                        RIGHT JOIN driver AS d ON d.vid = v.vid
                        WHERE v.sid = $value
                        ORDER BY v.vid DESC");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `NOT EXISTS` clause. There's an example here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/6839529/283366

Comment: @Phil let me check it.

Comment: Worst case, you could always split this complex query into 2 simple ones. First query for all unassigned vids and then fetch all vehicles that have an vid in this list.

Comment: @AdrianBaginski can show an example?

Comment: @AdrianBaginski how can get all unassigned vids? For that I need run some kind of join query, right?

Comment: this queries for all unassigned cars: `select vid from assigned where assigned_end < now() or assigned_start > now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select * from vehicle where vid not in ( 
    select vid from assigned where assigned_end < now() or assigned_start > now() 
)
```

Comment: Let me try with this.

Comment: I am using `select * from vehicle where not exist ( select vid from assigned where assigned_start < 1527804060 and assigned_end > 1527811320` but getting error message which is : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null

Comment: please use my updated query again. So no values were found - you should really switch to a debugging environment such as phpmyadmin :)

Comment: okay so just do the inner query and see what if it returns the right rows of data `select vid from assigned where assigned_end < now() or assigned_start > now()`

Comment: Yes, this inner query return 15 and 14

Comment: hmm, okay try "not in" instead of "not exists". Please see my updated query from the answer

Comment: try `...vid not in()`

Comment: Well, now I am using this : `select * from vehicle where vid not in (
    select vid from assigned where assigned_end < now() or assigned_start > now()
)` it's showing all vid without 15 and 14 but why you use now()?

Comment: I need to check against the date which I get from the booking date, right?

Comment: I know but I think I should check the data which I am getting from the reservation page not now(). Anyway, It seems I got the solution. Thanks a lot for your hard effort. Hero of the day :)

Comment: @ Adrian Baginski can you help me again?